# matlab: read from text file that not has specific format

Tags: matlab, text-files

How to read a text file that contains 2 lines header, then 1 to 3 or 4 lines numbers that I want to extract and save the numbers to array.

> # Sequence Data: seqnum=1;seqlen=700;
>
> # Model Data: run_type=Metagenomic
>
> 1_1_636_+
>
> # Sequence Data: seqnum=4;seqlen=700;seqhdr="frag4",
>
> # Model Data: run_type=Metagenomic;model="24|
>
> 1_3_302_+
>
> > 2_345_698_+

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to simply scan the text file line by line with `fgetl`:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    disp(tline)
end % for
fclose(fid);
```

Parameter `tline` then is a string which can be transferred to numbers part by part, e.g.:

```
numbers = [];
fid = fopen('file.txt');
fgetl(fid);
fgetl(fid);
tline = fgetl(fid);
tline = strsplit(tline,'_');
numbers = [numbers ; str2double(tline{1}) str2double(tline{2}) str2double(tline{3})];
fgetl(fid);
fgetl(fid);
tline = fgetl(fid);
tline = strsplit(tline,'_');
numbers = [numbers ; str2double(tline{1}) str2double(tline{2}) str2double(tline{3})];
tline = fgetl(fid);
tline = strsplit(tline,'_');
numbers = [numbers ; str2double(tline{1}) str2double(tline{2}) str2double(tline{3})];
fclose(fid);
```

Output:

```
numbers =
     1     1   636
     1     3   302
     2   345   698
```

A more general way, in case all comment lines begin with #:

```
numbers = [];
fid = fopen('file.txt','r');
while ~feof(fid)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~strcmp(tline(1),'#')
        tline = strsplit(tline,'_');
        numbers = [numbers ; str2double(tline{1}) str2double(tline{2}) str2double(tline{3})];
    end % if
end % for
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: is there a way to generalize the second code because I have a large file (2 lines header+ 1 to 3 line numbers)

Comment: `if ~strcmp(tline(1),'#')` ==> `if ~isempty(tline)&&~strcmp(tline(1),'#')`

Comment: Gelliant's comment is right, it considers cases of empty lines.